# Weird java behavior with casts to primitive types

Tags: java

This was probably asked somewhere but I couldn't find it. Could someone clarify why this code compiles and prints out `1`?

```
long i = (byte) + (char) - (int) + (long) - 1;
System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley: well, it looks weird, isn't it? Even though the answer is simple, and we understood it right after I posted the question.

Comment: *I* think it looks weird; I don't have any problem believing someone would look at that and not believe it was even legal Java.

Comment: long j = +-+- - -+-+ -+- + - +1; // this is also legal. As long as ++ or -- doesn't occur.

Comment: This is explained in the original post http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/10/java-plus.html ;)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's being parsed as this:

```
long i = (byte)( +(char)( -(int)( +(long)(-1) ) ) );
```

where all the `+` and `-` operators are unary `+` or `-`.

In which case, the `1` gets negated twice, so it prints out as a `1`.

Answer (score 5):

Because both '+' and '-' are [unary operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html), and the casts are working on the operands of those unaries. The rest is math.

Answer (score 5):

Unary operators and casting :)

+1 is legal

(byte) + 1 is casting +1 to a byte.

Sneaky! Made me think.