# Understanding java program

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weird java behavior with casts to primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924961/weird-java-behavior-with-casts-to-primitive-types)

Why following prints `1`?

```
int i = (char) - (int) + (long) - 1;
System.out.println(i);
```

Why above lines of code prints 1? How come the value of `i` become 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken,

```
int i = (char) - (int) + (long) - 1;
```

is actually equivalent to

```
int i = (char)(-(int)(+((long)(- 1))));
```

since -1 and 1 fit nicely into all data types used in the expression, we can drop the casts to get

```
int i = -(+(- 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way, with each expression getting its own variable (well, aside from the -1).

```
long a = (long) -1; // a = -1
int b = (int) a;    // b = -1
int c = -b;         // c = 1
int d = (char) c;   // d = 1
int i = (int) d;    // i = 1 (implicit conversion)
```