# Confusing type casting in Java

Tags: java, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weird java behavior with casts to primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924961/weird-java-behavior-with-casts-to-primitive-types)

Let's look at the following code snippet in Java.

```
package typecasting;

final public class TypeCasting
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i = (byte) + (char) - (int) + (long) - 1;
        System.out.print("\n i = "+i+"\n");
    }
}
```

The statement `System.out.print("\n i = "+i+"\n");` displays **i = 1**. How?

Comment: Oh, for the love of `$DEITY`... so many dups of this question. Hang on  a sec.

Comment: This example looked very familiar, and I swear I answered something similar a few weeks ago. Though it took me a while to find it, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924961/weird-java-behavior-with-casts-to-primitive-types Now that I look at it, even the example is identical. Voting as dupe.

Comment: Thanks @Myst, I wasn't having any luck digging through my history. Ah yes, and we both voted to close [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954268/understanding-java-program) as well. These must be coming from undergrad courses...

Comment: @MattBall: I had trouble finding it too. I had to sort my answers chronologically and search back several pages to find it.

Comment: This code is a bit hard to understand, but it is also monumentally stupid ... and you should never have to deal with it in real life.  (Job interviews maybe, but if you've go an interviewer asking questions like this, you probably don't want him as a co-worker.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code uses the unary `+` and `-` operators.

It's equivalent to `-(-1)` with a bunch of extra casts.  (the [unary `+` operator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.15.3) doesn't change the value)

Answer (score 4):

The line:

```
(byte) + (char) - (int) + (long) - 1;
```

is being parsed as:

```
(byte) (+(char) (-(int) (+(long)(-1) ) ) );
```

All the `+` and `-` are unary operators. Since there are two `-`, the `1` gets negated twice so the entire expression evaluates to `1`.

Answer (score 3):

The operators are being treated as *unary* + and *unary* -.

```
int i = (byte) (+ (char) (- (int) (+ (long) (- 1))));
```

Answer (score 2):

The JLS specifies the following:

```
 CastExpression:
    ( PrimitiveType Dimsopt ) UnaryExpression
    ( ReferenceType ) UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus
```

This means that any expression that is (Primitive Type) is followed by a UnaryExpression. If I take your statement and put `[]` around the unary expressions:

```
(byte) 
  [+(char) 
    [-(int) 
      [+(long) 
        [-1]
      ]
    ]
  ];
```