# What does Java compiler interprets by `(byte) + (char) - (int) + (long) - 1`?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weird java behavior with casts to primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924961/weird-java-behavior-with-casts-to-primitive-types)

Why does this code in Java,

```
int i = (byte) + (char) - (int) + (long) - 1;
System.out.println(i);
```

prints 1? Why does it even compile?

Source: [Java Code Geeks](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/10/weird-funny-java.html)

Comment: Source for source http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/10/java-plus.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you are doing is combining type casts with unary operators.

So let's see:

First, you have the value `-1`, which you cast to the type `long`.

Then, you perform the unary operation `+`, which doesn't change the value, so you still have `(long) -1`.

Then, you cast it to int, so we now have `int -1`. Then, you use unary operator `-`, so we have `-(-1)`, which is `1`.

Then you cast it to char, so we have `char 1`. Then, you use unary operator `+`, so you still have `1`.

Finally, the value is cast to `byte`, so you have `byte 1`. And then it is once again (implicitly) cast to `int`.

Answer (score 5):

The various `(<type>)` parts are just casting between various types. So what happens is, reading from the right, `1` -> `-1` -> `(long)-1` -> `(int)-1` -> `-(int)-1 = 1` -> `(char)1)` -> `(byte)1` which then gets cast to an `int` during the assignment. At no point does the type cast result in effective change of the value, so the entire first line is equivalent to `int i = 1;`.

Answer (score 2):

This goes right to left.  -1 gets cast to long.  Then the + prefix is applied (which has no effect), and it's cast to int.  Then the - gets applied (changing it to 1) and it gets cast to char.  Lastly, the + prefix is applied (which still has no effect) and it's cast to byte.

Answer (score 0):

lets add parenthesis:

```
int i = ((byte) + ((char) - ((int) + ((long) (- 1)))));
System.out.println(i);
```

basically this is just a series of casts and unary operators (`+` does nothing, `-` negates)

the full program flow is in [luiscubal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9651790/731620)'s answer