# How the output of the the code below is '1'?

Tags: java, primitive

I tried the same code by replacing default values in the code below, I got '-1'. But the actual output is '1'. How???

```
 int i = (byte) + (char) - (int) + (long) - 1;

            System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: What values did you replace default values with?

Comment: int i = (int) (0+0-0+0L-1); @MoisheLipsker

Comment: You misinterpreted this. `(long)` is not 0. All the operators here are unary.

Comment: And just a side note: `0` is an `int`, not a `byte` or `char`, so you changed the types as well.

Comment: This is a duplicate.  The challenge is finding the other.

Comment: @DavidWallace Challenge accepted. :-)

Comment: Shucks, I had http://stackoverflow.com/q/9651760

Answer (score 4):

`i` will be evaluated as `(+(-(+(-1)))`, which will be evaluated as `(-(-1))`, which is `1`.